# Create 3 tables from 1 table in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database of horse racing data. The data is scraped from the net, into excel and then into a single table `Race_Master` in a MS SQL database.

The columns include such data as:

```
date
pos
odds
btnby
going
horsename
trainername
jockeyname
```

Of course, the names of the horses, jockeys and trainers are stored in an inefficient and non-relational way, there are many duplicated entry's. So I have created 3 new tables:

```
horse_name
trainer_name
jockey_name
```

There are no duplicates in any of those tables.

How can I now create a new table which will take the data from `Race_Master` and instead of using the names of the horses trainers and jockeys, refer to those respective tables and use their id's as a reference?

Comment: Is your question "How to create ...?" or "How to insert into ...?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have created a table then.....

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (MasterID, JockeyID, TrainerID, HorseID)
SELECT M.MasterID, J.JockeyID, T.TrainerID , H.HorseID
FROM Race_Master M
INNER JOIN  Jockeys J   ON M.JockeyName = J.JockeyName
INNER JOIN  Trainer T   ON M.TrainerName = T.TrainerName
INNER JOIN  Horse   H   ON M.HorseName   = H.HorseName
```

If you want to create a table on the fly

```
SELECT M.MasterID, J.JockeyID, T.TrainerID , H.HorseID
  INTO New_Table
FROM Race_Master M
INNER JOIN  Jockeys J   ON M.JockeyName = J.JockeyName
INNER JOIN  Trainer T   ON M.TrainerName = T.TrainerName
INNER JOIN  Horse   H   ON M.HorseName   = H.HorseName
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks to all who replied

Answer (score 0):

To create the table:

```
create table dbo.Race(
     ID    int identity not null primary key
    ,JockeyID  int references dbo.Jockey(ID)
    ,HorseID   int references dbo.Horse(ID)
    ,TrainerID int references dbo.Trainer(ID)
)
go
```

And to insert it's rows:

```
with 
jockey as (
    select JockeyID 
    from dbo.Jockey j
    join dbo.Race_Master 
      on Race_Master.JockeyName = j.JockeyName
),
trainer as (
    select TrainerID 
    from dbo.Trainer t
    join dbo.Race_Master 
      on Race_Master.TrainerName = t.TrainerName
),
horse as (
    select HorseID 
    from dbo.HOrse h
    join dbo.Race_Master 
      on Race_Master.HorseName = h.HorseName
)
insert Race(JockeyID,HorseID,TrainerID)
select jockey.ID,horse.ID,trainer.ID;
```